# como guardar posición de checks html y PHP?

Tags: php, html, web, formularios, input

buen día.

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es mostrar una lista de N numero de checks con en un ciclo y que estos envie un valor de Verdadero cuando alguien seleccione un check y un False cuando no se seleccione ningún check y que guarde los valores en la base de datos para después mostrar los resultados en el orden correcto y mostrarlo. ya que lo guarda pero no en el orden correcto

```js
<?php 
$valor= $_POST['checks'];
$ancho=4;

for($y=0; $y<$ancho; $y++)
{
    $arre[$y]=$y;
}

for($i=0; $i<$ancho; $i++) 
{
    if($valor[$i]==$arre[$i])
    {
        $dado[$i]="Verdadero,";
    }
    else
    {
        $dado[$i]="Falso,";
    }
}

for($j=0; $j<$ancho; $j++)
{
    echo $dado[$j];
}

?>
```

```html
<form action="prueba.php" method="POST">
Prueba 1<input type='checkbox' role='checkbox'  name='checks[]' /><br>
Prueba 2<input type='checkbox' role='checkbox'  name='checks[]' /><br>
Prueba 3<input type='checkbox' role='checkbox'  name='checks[]' /><br>
Prueba 4<input type='checkbox' role='checkbox'  name='checks[]' /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te lo guarda desordenado porque solo los checkbox que han sido marcados por el usuario son enviados por POST. Si quieres guardar también los que no han sido marcados por el usuario puedes asignar un value a cada checkbox y luego comprobar cual ha sido marcado:

```
<form action="prueba.php" method="POST">
Prueba 1<input type='checkbox' role='checkbox'  name='checks[]' value='1'><br>
Prueba 2<input type='checkbox' role='checkbox'  name='checks[]' value='2'><br>
Prueba 3<input type='checkbox' role='checkbox'  name='checks[]' value='3'><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

<?php 
$valor= $_POST['checks'];
$ancho=4;
$arreglo=array();
$x=0;
$y=0;

while($x<$ancho){
   if($valor[$y]==$x+1){
      $arreglo[$x]="Verdadero";
      $y++;
      $x++;
   }else{
      $arreglo[$x]="Falso";
      $x++;
   }
}

?>
```

Como ves, en el array valor donde se guardan los checkbox marcados solo entraran los checkbox marcados por el usuario. Pero si sabemos el total de los checkbox, con la ayuda del value podemor ver cuales estan marcados y cuales no.

En este caso, cuando el checkbox esta marcado entro "Verdadero" al array que lo guarda y aumento una posición en el array $valor. Si el checkbox con el value no existe entro "Falso" pero no aumento una posición en $valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya quedo.